# How to show live ads in iPhone device in React native?

Tags: react-native, admob

I have integrated react-native-admob and I have set test device id to Emulator .But for release I want to show live ads .How to achieve this .I am stuck now please need help.

Comment: Did you try dev flag? `if(__DEV__) { id="PUTTESTIDHERE"; } else { id="PUTLIVEIDHERE" }` and you can simply add the id to `react-native-admob` component

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I am using the live ad id from Admob. It throws me an error saying  " Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}"

Comment: No ad to show. means that there is no ad for your admob id to show. Which id are you using? `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712` is the test id of `react-native-admob`

Comment: and I think admob only supports interstitial and banner ads.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake. I was using Banner Ad unit id to show the Interstitial ad in-app. I got it fixed by replacing correct ad unit id.

Comment: glad you found the problem.